# Grep or egrep to exclude text in a line

Tags: grep

I would like some advice on how to exclude a word in a line using grep but still keep the line?

So I have tried:

```
grep -v '1.942134' results.tbl | egrep '*.fits' results.tbl
```

to try to list all the string with extension .fits but exclude "1.942134" in the sentence but it still returns the full lines.

Any advice?

Comment: Should be as simple as `grep '.fits' results.tbl | grep -v '1.942134'`. Note the pipe means you don't have to provide the file again, because the input is the output of the previous command.

Answer (score 0):

You should pipe to [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). Sed has lots of abilities, some of them more complicated than others, but one of its best is regexp substitutions.

```
grep '\.fits$' | sed 's/1.942134//'
```

Comment: You are over-matching in the grep pattern. There is no reason for the leading `.*` it doesn't add anything `'\.fits'` is enough (unless a line that starts with ".fits" should not match). The OP also didn't indicate a eol anchor. You probably also want to add word-boundaries to the sed to make that only match words.

Comment: How are you sure that `.fits` will be at the end of the line `$`? OP does not say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `awk`

```
awk '/\.fits/ && !/1\.942134/` results.tbl
```

PS you should escape the `.` in both `sed` and `awk` or else it will mean just any character.